# Cómo cambio colores de tablas y de columnas

Tags: php, css

Tengo esta comprobación la cual me trae un icono en la pantalla en una tabla:

```
if($resultado['informe'])
  $cerrado_sistema = "<i class=\"fal fa-exclamation-triangle\"></i>";
else
  $cerrado_sistema = '';
```

Pero quiero cambiar ese icono por un color rojo que ocupe todo el `tr`. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Éste es el código PHP relacionado (está dentro de un bucle que va generando las filas):

```
if($resultado['informe'])
  $cerrado_sistema = "<i class=\"fal fa-exclamation-triangle\"></i>";
else
  $cerrado_sistema = '';

if($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 2 || $_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 4)
    echo "<tr ".$cierrep.">
      <td><a class=\"btn\" href=\"checkTicket-1-".$resultado['id_ticket']."\">".$resultado['id_ticket']."</a></td>
      <td>".$resultado_usuario['personaNombre']." ".$resultado_usuario['apellido']."</td>
      <td>".$resultado_usuario['nombreDepartamento']."</td>
      <td>".$cede."</td>
      <td>".$solicitud."</td>
      <td>".$prioridad."</td>
      <td>".$resultado['titulo']."</td>
      <td>".$archivo."</td>
      <td>".$status."</td>
      <td>".$fecha[2]."/".$fecha[1]."/".$fecha[0]."</td>
      <td>".$hora."</td>
    </tr>";
else
    echo "<tr ".$cierrep.">
      <td><a class=\"btn\" href=\"checkTicket-1-".$resultado['id']."\">".$resultado['id']."</a></td>
      <td>".$resultado_usuario['personaNombre']." ".$resultado_usuario['apellido']."</td>
      <td>".$resultado_usuario['nombreDepartamento']."</td>
      <td>".$cede."</td>
      <td>".$solicitud."</td>
      <td>".$prioridad."</td>
      <td>".$resultado['titulo']."</td>
      <td>".$archivo."</td>
      <td>".$status."</td>
      <td>".$fecha[2]."/".$fecha[1]."/".$fecha[0]."</td>
      <td>".$hora."</td>
      <td>".$cerrado_sistema."</td>
    </tr>";
```

> NdE: La variable `$cierrep` puede tener los valores `""` o `class="danger"`.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar algo más de código? Por ejemplo, ¿dónde y cómo creas la fila?

Comment: si, sin problemas

Comment: el esta en 0 salvo se modifique el valor de "informe" mediante insert en la base de datos


 function informar($conexion, $id){

  mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE ticket
         set 
         informe = 1
         WHERE id = ".$id."")  
         or die("Error enviando informe: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
 }

Comment: Hola @JuanOrtiz, lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve]. Es fácil ayudarte con la pregunta, pero había tanto código que se perdía uno entre tantas líneas.

Comment: un saludo @AlvaroMontoro , que tal? si bueno, de verdad ya me pongo en eso.
pense que mostrar el codigo completo seria mejor para asi despejar dudas sobre lo que estoy haciendo . ya me estoy leyendo los del ejemplo minimo, pero se ejecutaria aqui en la web ? 
apenas empiezo con esto ya sabes. (y)

Comment: no entiendo eso sobre el NdE...
tu me dices algo como echo "<tr ".$cierrep." class=\"danger\">??

Comment: Pero si lo que hago alli es comprobar si el usuario es un administrador o no para mostrar todos los tickets y que el usuario solo vea los suyos. @AlvaroMontoro ¿cómo me ayudaría eso con el problema que tengo?

Comment: Hola Juan, es muy facil hacer lo que dices, usando css. Tienes la posibilidad de agregar codigo css a tu proyecto?

Comment: yo opte por colocar otro iconos , uno de color verde y otro rojo con otro elemento en la tabla html llamada estatus donde se imprime esos 2 elementos bien sea el caso.


 if($resultado['informe'])
                  $cerrado_sistema = "<i class=\"fa fa-exclamation\" title=\"PENDIENTE\"  style=\"color:red\"   ></i>";
                else
                  $cerrado_sistema = "<i class=\"fa fa-check\" title=\"CERRADO\" style=\"color:green\"></i>";

Comment: si @FacundoFernandez

Comment: @JuanOrtiz lo puse como nota porque aparece en el código y es relevante por el contenido que tiene (aunque personalmente quitaría el HTML y lo limitaría sólo al valor de la clase lo cual simplificaría tu código)

Comment: La cosa es que lo del informe no se muestra explicitamente en el navegador, es un resultado de la base de datos @FacundoFernandez
¿cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Podrias agregar algo como
.danger td:last-child{
  background:red
} . Modificando los estilos de la celda cuando tienes la clase danger. Siempre y cuando, hagas referencia a la ultima celda, sino tendrias que ponerle un id a esa celda.

Comment: mmmm no estoy muy claro como es css...
la cosa es que no precisamente me traigo un td sino un <i>

"<td  style=\"td:last-child{ background:red } \"   ></td>" y esto no me funciona.

Comment: yo creo que lo dejare asi, se entiende pero mejor hubiera sido con el color sobre todo el tr como tal amigos .

Comment: Te recomiendo que investigues sobre css, el modo en que me mostraste no es el correcto de como se coloca estilos. Te va a solucionar problemas en el futuro saber sobre css. No es complicado lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: asi le doy el estilo al <i class=\"fa fa-exclamation\" title=\"PENDIENTE\"  style=\"color:red\"   ></i>";  recuerda que uso php , no se como conectar ambos asi...

Comment: verdad que esta dificil? 
@FacundoFernandez

Answer (score 1):

La principal dificultad que presenta el código es que las variables no contienen valores sino HTML con etiquetas y atributos (algo que personalmente no recomendaría).

Parece que `$cierrep` solo se usa para poner la clase a la fila de la tabla, entonces si cambias `$cierrep` para que sólo contenga el nombre de la clase que quieres añadir ("danger" o nada), el código se simplifica considerablemente. Así, donde hacers `$cierrep = "class=\"danger\"";` tan sólo haz `$cierrep = "danger";`. Y luego en la fila pones `<tr class='".$cierrep."'>`, con lo que obtendrás el mismo resultado.

Una vez hecho eso, cambia `$cerrado_sistema` para que en lugar de tener un icono, lo que contenga sea el nombre de una clase, y se la asignas también a la clase de la fila (del mismo modo que haces con `$cierrep`). Dándole estilos con CSS para que aparezca de otro color. Por ejemplo define la clase `.cerrado_sistema` en tu CSS para que tenga fondo rojo:

```
.cerrado_sistema {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Y con los cambios de `$cierrep` y `$cerrado_sistema` especificados arriba:

```
if($resultado['informe'])
  $cerrado_sistema = "cerrado_sistema";
else
  $cerrado_sistema = '';

if($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 2 || $_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 4)
    echo "<tr class='".$cierrep." ".$cerrado_sistema."'>
      <td><a class=\"btn\" href=\"checkTicket-1-".$resultado['id_ticket']."\">".$resultado['id_ticket']."</a></td>
      <td>".$resultado_usuario['personaNombre']." ".$resultado_usuario['apellido']."</td>
      <td>".$resultado_usuario['nombreDepartamento']."</td>
      <td>".$cede."</td>
      <td>".$solicitud."</td>
      <td>".$prioridad."</td>
      <td>".$resultado['titulo']."</td>
      <td>".$archivo."</td>
      <td>".$status."</td>
      <td>".$fecha[2]."/".$fecha[1]."/".$fecha[0]."</td>
      <td>".$hora."</td>
    </tr>";
else
    echo "<tr class='".$cierrep." ".$cerrado_sistema."'>
      <td><a class=\"btn\" href=\"checkTicket-1-".$resultado['id']."\">".$resultado['id']."</a></td>
      <td>".$resultado_usuario['personaNombre']." ".$resultado_usuario['apellido']."</td>
      <td>".$resultado_usuario['nombreDepartamento']."</td>
      <td>".$cede."</td>
      <td>".$solicitud."</td>
      <td>".$prioridad."</td>
      <td>".$resultado['titulo']."</td>
      <td>".$archivo."</td>
      <td>".$status."</td>
      <td>".$fecha[2]."/".$fecha[1]."/".$fecha[0]."</td>
      <td>".$hora."</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>";
```

Ya no hace falta mostrar el valor en la última celda y si `$cerrado_sistema` se cumple, toda la fila se pondrá del color especificado en el CSS (en este caso rojo).

Comment: una consulta @Alvaro Montoro, tu estas colocando en el codigo que se muestre el color rojo si se cumple una condicion pero veo que en la linea donde esta el tr de la tabla tienen las 2 clases de color rojo, no he probado aun el codigo porque no tengo acceso al sistema por ahora, pero , no deberia quitarle esa clase que es la que muestra ese color cuando el valor es false en mi condicion=? 
gracias por estar siempre atento a los post

Comment: @JuanOrtiz aunque se estén asignando las variables, si están vacías la clase quedará vacía y no se verá roja. La cosa es si las dos tienen valor deberías poner una precedencia (a no ser que sea el mismo tono de rojo y no importe).

Comment: el lunes intentare hacer la modificacion de mi codigo analizando tu ejemplo , ya comentare luego como me fue, gracias y feliz domingo